# Choice in a Batch File messagebox ok - cancel

Tags: batch-file

I want to launch a website with a batch file and have buttons for **ok** and **cancel**. If the user 
clicks on the **ok** button open the website and if they click on **cancel** nothing happens. So far I have this:

```
@echo off
start iexplore google.fr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@ECHO OFF
:MENU
CLS
ECHO #########################
ECHO # Visit Google Homepage?#
ECHO #########################
ECHO.
ECHO.
set /P c=Visit Google Homepage ?[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :VISIT
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :MENU
goto :MENU
:VISIT
start iexplore google.fr
goto :MENU
```

Comment: its working. but i need message box with buttons yes and no.

Comment: the only way you are going to get a dialog style batch file is with a tool like [WBAT](http://www.horstmuc.de/ui.htm). use the link to check it out. menues, buttons, input fields, checkboxes, radio buttons, list selection with batch files,i've used it and it's easy to do.

Comment: Download [WBAT here](http://www.horstmuc.de/int/wbat250.zip) and then run Demo.bat

Comment: thx ...the problem is your mass have always this file WBAT.COM